# How to crawl multi-page in 1 spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a beginner with Scrapy, I want to build a crawl job with many pages in 1 spider.

FYI: this is an e-commerce page, the job should go page after page to find all products. For every product found, open its own URL to crawl data for that specific product.

The code should following this:

1. Open a page with an URL (page 1)
2. Found all products
3. Loop every product -> follow its URL -> crawl data
4. Found the next page
5. Follow the next page

Here is my code

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "acfc_spider"

    #List of URL
    def start_reqeust(self):
        urls =[
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/nam/promotion.html?p=2",
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/nu/promotion.html?p=1",
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/outlet.html?p=1",
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/tre-em/khuyen-mai.html?p=1"
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    
    #Crawl the product detail
    def parse_product_detail(self, response):
        with open('datail_product.txt', 'a') as wr:
            wr.write('Crawled this detail product with URL ' + str(response.request.url) + '\n')

    #Crawl page after page
    def parse(self, response):
        with open('general_product.txt', 'a') as wr:
            wr.write(response.request.url + '\n')

        #Found all products
        list_of_product = response.css("li.item.product.product-item  a::attr(href)").getall()

        #Go to the page of a specific product to do crawl
        for i in list_of_product:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=i, callback=self.parse_product_detail)

        #Go to the next page and repeat
        current_page = (response.request.url)[-1:]
        next_page = str(int(current_page)+1)
        list_of_page = response.css("li.item a.page").xpath("@href").extract()
        next_page_url = [i for i in list_of_page if i[-1] == next_page]
        yield response.follow(next_page_url, self.parse)
```

For now I just make it write a log into a file `.txt`

But when I command `scrapy crawl acfc_spider`, I got this

```
2021-11-25 16:39:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-11-25 16:39:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-11-25 16:39:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-11-25 16:39:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-11-25 16:39:22 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.005,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 25, 9, 39, 22, 162166),
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 25, 9, 39, 22, 157166)}
2021-11-25 16:39:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

In the end, I did not find any of my log `.txt`  file. Something must be wrong but I don't know why.

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `start_reqeust` instead of `start_requests`.

Second, you're trying to follow a list:

```py
next_page_url = [i for i in list_of_page if i[-1] == next_page]
yield response.follow(next_page_url, self.parse)
```

Also you don't need all that pages just to get to the next page.

Here is the complete code (BTW consider to use scrapy's [FEEDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEEDS) for your scraped results):

```py
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "acfc_spider"

    #List of URL
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/nam/promotion.html?p=1",
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/nu/promotion.html?p=1",
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/outlet.html?p=1",
            "https://www.acfc.com.vn/tre-em/khuyen-mai.html?p=1"
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    #Crawl the product detail
    def parse_product_detail(self, response):
        with open('datail_product.txt', 'a') as wr:
            wr.write(f'Crawled this detail product with URL {str(response.request.url)}\n')

    #Crawl page after page
    def parse(self, response):
        with open('general_product.txt', 'a') as wr:
            wr.write(response.request.url + '\n')

        #Found all products
        list_of_product = response.css('a.product-item-link::attr(href)').getall()

        #Go to the page of a specific product to do crawl
        for i in list_of_product:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=i, callback=self.parse_product_detail)

        #Go to the next page and repeat
        next_page_url = response.css('.next::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page_url:
            yield response.follow(next_page_url)
```